# Mat Tree Toggle Options

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface, angular-material, frontend

I am using mat tree toggle from material angular and finding it hard to toggle between expand and collapse. Eg. If I click on one of the items in tree, it should expand and then if I click on another to expand, it should collapse the previously open. Like we do in case of accordions. All the help is highly appreciated. Attaching my code below

```html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
    <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding
        [style.background]="treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? '#DEEAFF' : ''">
        <mat-list-item routerLink="{{node.path}}">{{node.name}}</mat-list-item>
    </mat-tree-node>

    <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding
        [style.background]="treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? '#DEEAFF' : ''">
        <mat-list-item>
            <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle disableRipple [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
                {{node.name}}
            </button>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror" color="primary">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more'}}
        </mat-icon>
    </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a click event to matTreeNodeToggle to trigger the collapsing logic
- Fetch the parent node and collapse all the descendants
- Expand only the clicked node and the parent node if available

```js
nodeClicked(node) {
  if (this.treeControl.isExpanded(node)) {
    let parent = null;

    let index = this.treeControl.dataNodes.findIndex((n) => n === node);

    for (let i = index; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (node.level > this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].level) {
        parent = this.treeControl.dataNodes[i];
        break;
      }
    }

    if(parent){
    this.treeControl.collapseDescendants(parent);
    this.treeControl.expand(parent);
  } else {
    this.treeControl.collapseAll()
  }
    this.treeControl.expand(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle disableRipple [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name" (click)=nodeClicked(node)>
  {{node.name}}
</button>
```